# windows cannot load bitmap image

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010

This program just shows a blank window.

I want to load bitmap image randomly onto the screen. I am not able to figure this out. Even if I give different name to image in this program the program still executes without any error and shows the blank window.

Please help me!

```
#ifndef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#endif

/*have used unicode */

#include<Windows.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<time.h>
using namespace std;

bool gameover =FALSE;
const wchar_t classname[] = L"My first procedure and main";
HWND window;
HDC device;
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd,UINT uMsg,WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam);


ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    //set the new windows properties 
    WNDCLASS wc = {};

    wc.lpfnWndProc=(WNDPROC)WindowProc;
    wc.hInstance=hInstance;
    wc.style=CS_HREDRAW|CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.hbrBackground=(HBRUSH)GetStockObject(COLOR_WINDOW +1);
    wc.lpszClassName=classname;

    return RegisterClass(&wc);
}

bool InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance,int nCmdShow)
{ 
    //Create a new window
    window=CreateWindowEx(0,
                          classname,
                          L"My Program",
                          WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
                          CW_USEDEFAULT,CW_USEDEFAULT,CW_USEDEFAULT,CW_USEDEFAULT,
                          NULL,
                          NULL,
                          hInstance,
                          NULL );

    //Any error in creating the window ?
    if(window==0)
        return 0;

    //Display the window 
    ShowWindow(window,nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(window);
    device=GetDC(window);
    return 1;
}

bool Game_Init()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    return 1;
}

// This function handles the loading of bitmap image into the window
void DrawBitmap( char *filename,int x,int y)
{
    //Load the bitmap image
    HBITMAP image=(HBITMAP)LoadImage(0,L"image.bmp",IMAGE_BITMAP,0,0,LR_LOADFROMFILE);
    BITMAP bm;
    GetObject(image,sizeof(BITMAP),&bm);
    HDC hdcdevice=CreateCompatibleDC(device);
    SelectObject(hdcdevice,image);
    BitBlt(device,x,y,bm.bmWidth,bm.bmHeight,hdcdevice,0,0,SRCCOPY);

    //delete the device context and bitmap
    DeleteDC(hdcdevice);
    DeleteObject((HBITMAP)image);
}

void Game_Run()
{
    if(gameover==true)
        return;
    RECT rect;
    GetClientRect(window,&rect);

    //draw bitmap at random location
    int x=rand() % (rect.right-rect.left);
    int y=rand() %(rect.bottom-rect.top);

    DrawBitmap("image.bmp",x,y);
}

void Game_End()
{
    //Free the device
    ReleaseDC(window,device);
}

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,HINSTANCE,PWSTR PCmdLine,int nCmdShow)
{   
    //Register the class    
    MyRegisterClass(hInstance);

    //Initialize application
    if(!InitInstance(hInstance,nCmdShow))
        return 0;

    //Declare variables
    MSG msg ={ };

    //Initialize the game
    if(!Game_Init())
        return 0;

    //main message loop
    while(!gameover)
    {
        if (PeekMessage(&msg,NULL,0,0,PM_REMOVE))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
        Game_Run();
    }
    Game_End();

    return msg.wParam;
}

//This is window procedure function for handling closing of windows.
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd,UINT uMsg,WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam)
{   
    switch(uMsg) 
    { 
        case WM_CLOSE: 
            if(MessageBox(hwnd,L"Do you want to close this window",NULL,MB_OKCANCEL)==IDOK)           
                gameover=true;
            DestroyWindow(hwnd);


    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd,uMsg,wParam,lParam);
}
```

[image: This is the output of my program]

Comment: i tried adding image to debug folder also but its not happening

Comment: If the program shows a blank window, it is executing. The title of your question is confusing.

Comment: to get any errors you first should check for errors. alternatively, use debugger and check all return values by it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass the full path of the bmp file to the LoadImage function. Also check the return value of the LoadImage function.

For eg.

```
HBITMAP image=(HBITMAP)LoadImage(0,L"c:\\wherever\\whatever\\image.bmp",IMAGE_BITMAP,0,0,LR_LOADFROMFILE);
if(image == NULL)
    MessageBox(0, "Couldn't load the image", "Error", MB_OK);
else
    .... Whatever else ......
```

Almost certainly, your LoadImage is failing to find "image.bmp" and hence returning NULL.

Comment: Message box popped up showing couldn't load the image.I tried including path also but its not working.

Comment: @NaveenGabriel - Can you copy paste your exact LoadImage call here with the path?

Comment: @NaveenGabriel - can you copy/paste the line of code here - where you call LoadImage with the path of the image? To answer your Q, MSVC typically initializes uninitialized pointers with 0xcccccccc

Comment: @user93353-HBITMAP image=(HBITMAP)LoadImage(0,L"A:\output\c++\GameLoop\Debug\image.bmp",IMAGE_BITMAP,0,0,LR_LOADFROMFILE);

Comment: @NaveenGabriel - change the path to L"A:\\output\\c++\\GameLoop\\Debug\\image.bmp" - it will work then. Backslashes have to be escaped by another backslash. See in any answer answer also - I have 2 backslashes in the path everywhere.

Comment: @user93353-still no change in output.

Comment: Open a command window & type "dir A:\output\c++\GameLoop\Debug\image.bmp" - Do you actually have a image.bmp at that path?

Comment: @user93353-yes it does have image.bmp

Comment: Then call GetLastError after LoadImage to see why LoadImage failed.

Answer (score 0):

Check the values of your handles like "device" and "image".

Try and step through the code and see if everything is working how it should be.

You also have the option of using LoadBitmap().

Comment: I am using 64 bit windows 8 OS.

Comment: How would i know whether it is 8 bit bitmap?

Comment: In Windows right-click on the file then properties then summary.

Comment: Try a different bitmap and see if you still get 0xcccccccc

Comment: i used different bitmap still the value of image is 0xcccccccc.

Comment: Well, I got your code to work so the file that you are trying to load may not be accessible for some reason. Perhaps file access rights of some sort?

Comment: Yes, it works fine. Just needed to uncomment the WinProc and stuff. Also changed wWinMain to WinMain to run it on Dev-C++.

Comment: But it is not running in visual studio 2010.

Comment: Finally my code worked.I created my own bmp image and inserted into the code and it worked.